# contenteditable DIV has a default border in FF & Chrome - How to hide it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, google-chrome

**Chrome - 11.0.696.50**
**FF - 4.0**
**IE - 7.0.570.13**

The DIV is defined as below and when I'm focusing on it with jQuery.
As soon as I focus on it a border appears around the DIV in both FF & Chrome.

FF shows a dotted border & Chrome shows a solid light orange one.

I tried `border: none;` but that doesn't make  difference. Any ideas ?

DIV : `<DIV id="editable-div" contentEditable="true"></DIV>`

CSS for it :

`#editable-div

{

  margin-left: 10px;

  margin-top: 10px;

  width: 740px;

  height: 25px;

  border: none;

  direction: ltr;

  text-align: left;

}`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What you're seeing is probably an [*outline*, not technically a border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158515/difference-between-outline-and-border). Try this:

```
#editable-div:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

This is kind of a shot in the dark on my part; hopefully if it doesn't work exactly this way at least it will help you figure out a solution.

Comment: Tested and this does work (Chrome 12.0.742.0 at least): http://jsfiddle.net/vG9JQ/

Comment: Thanks Paul ! this worked. Seems I can't accept the answer within 10 mins. of it being asked. Interesting..

Comment: @Paul, thanks!! Worked like a charm. This problem was beginning to drive me crazy

Comment: Does not work on Chromium 37.0.2062.120 or FF 31.4.0