# Difference between outline and border properties

Tags: css

Somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1158515/866022).

Outline and border are pretty similar (although they do have their differences, as explained in the referenced question), but they use exactly the same properties/values in the opposite order. For example:

```
border: 1px solid black;
outline: black solid 1px;
```

To me, this seems to be a glaring inconsistency that should have been avoided. When using both borders and outlines, it is easy to mix up the order and write invalid CSS. Is there any known reason these two similar items have the same values written in the opposite order?

**EDIT:**

It seems (at least in IE8) that both can (sometimes) accept the values in either order and work fine, which makes it seem a bit stranger that the standard would be to write them in these different ways.

Comment: Where do you have this information from?

Comment: A CSS book (http://www.amazon.com/Stylin-CSS-Designers-Guide-2nd/dp/0321525566/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1316442755&sr=8-1) and Visual Studio's intellisense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect. Both properties' shorthands except values to be in the order `width`, `style`, and `color`.

See

- http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border
- http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/outline

You can probably mix them as you wish and it'll still work,  but that is the browser being lenient.

Comment: I thought that was the case, but I started questioning it when I hit a bug (unreproducible) where javascript was intermittently throwing an error when I tried to set css "outline:1px solid red" saying that it was invalid. It works usually, but "outline:red solid 1px" always works.

Comment: All CSS shorthand properties allow their orders to be mixed up, as long as that doesn't result in an ambiguity. Thus both `border` and `outline` can be specified in any order, whereas `font` cannot.

Comment: @Jim: That makes no sense. You probably can't reproduce it because the error is to do with something else.

Comment: @Spudley ah, fair enough - I can indeed not think of a possible ambiguity. Would be worthy of an answer on its own, wouldn't it? (Deleting mine soon)