# On hover over li make second row li move

Tags: html, css

I am trying to show border color on hover over the list of items. When i move mouse over first row items, the second row items move towards right. Please check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmpm/gsytL63h/)

```
<ul class="tiles">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
ul.tiles { width: 400px; }
ul.tiles li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: white;
}
ul.tiles li:hover {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of `border` use `outline` because `border` increase adds padding to the element.  (`ul.tiles li:hover {
    outline: 1px solid black;
}`)

Comment: It worked. Is it the right way to do it.

Comment: It depends.  currently you're not adding radius to the border and it is not one-sided too (example: border-left, right, etc.,).  In your case `outline` is pretty enough.

Comment: Here you can find good explanation http://stackoverflow.com/q/1158515/1671639

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a transparent border to your `li`:

```
li {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

---

```css
ul.tiles { width: 400px; }
ul.tiles li {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: white;
}
ul.tiles li:hover {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

ul.tiles li {
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tiles">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can user `box-sizing: border-box;` on the `ul.tiles li`
http://jsfiddle.net/gm8zvfsk/

> The box-sizing property is used to tell the browser what the sizing
>   properties (width and height) should include.
>
> Should they include the border-box or just the content-box which is
>   the default value of the width and height properties.
>
> For example, if you want two bordered boxes side by side, it can be
>   achieved through setting box-sizing to "border-box". This forces the
>   browser to render the box with the specified width and height, and
>   place the border and padding inside the box.

Comment: In this case, the text moves, which is not very ideal.

Answer (score 0):

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47bb6azr/).

As Praveen said, using outline fixes the issue.

```
ul.tiles li:hover {
    outline: 1px solid black;
}
```