# How to achieve box-sizing functionality with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, border-box

So I found out the hard way that flexbox doesn't respect the `box-sizing: border-box;` CSS declaration. Fine. But is there some way to get that functionality using a flexbox layout?

Check out [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a69r38z6/). We have 3 rows with 3 boxes in each row. I'd like all the boxes to be the same size. The middle box in the middle row has some margin & border properties making it bigger. In the box model, we would solve that with `box-sizing: border-box`. Is there some equivalent in the flexbox model?

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(function() {    
  for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    $('<div class="row" id="row' + i + '">').appendTo($('#grid'));
    
    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if(i === 2 && j === 1) {
        $('<div class="box2">').appendTo($('#row' + i));
      } else {
        $('<div class="box">').appendTo($('#row' + i));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 25px solid cornflowerblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  background: pink;
}

.box2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 25px solid purple;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="grid"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: @Max - how did you edit the post to include the code on the page like that?

Comment: Glad you asked! [Here's a blog post explaining](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: I also just noticed that the demo doesn't really work if you just click "run demo" without full screening it. I edited your code to be `html {height: 300px;}` so it better illustrates what you're trying to show. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason for a margin and border? The border I guess is for aesthetics? If so substitute border with outline. Why is the margin necessary if your'e using flexbox?

Comment: @zer00ne The outline substitution is definitely a good idea, but [by using outline instead of border we lose some customization options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20398566/2234742). Ideally there is a solution that lets us continue using `border`, but if not, your suggestion seems like a good workaround.

Comment: True with outline, you can't use border-radius and there's no left, right, top, or bottom outline either. Try my answer out, see if it works.

Comment: Note `box-sizing` does work with flex-box. However, `flex-grow` distributes available space by increasing the width of the flex items, ignoring whether they have borders.

Comment: I agree, the OP Maximillian Laurneidter a.k.a. The Qodesmith would not accept that. He has convinced himself that `box-sizing` is completely non-functioning in a flexbox environment, no matter what I showed him.  I will totally avoid any questions having to do with @MaximillianLaumeister and @TheQodesmith in the future.

Comment: Dear @zer00ne, please note that I am not the OP (Qodesmith), I am just an editor, and therefore I am not notified when new answers are posted to this question. A few minutes ago when I got your previous chat message in my inbox, I was about to look at the new answer you provided, and if it worked, I was planning to upvote it. The screenshot you posted as a comment on your answer looked very promising, as it indeed showed the desired behavior. Before I could run your code, however, you deleted your answer. If your answer worked as you claim, then it's a shame that you decided to delete it.

Comment: The proof was there then a long back and forth between you and I. It wouldn't be useful to anyone since I had to go from this to that trying show you what I meant. A waste of time I'm not going to repeat.

Comment: @zer00ne I still believe you have me confused with the OP. I don't remember any such back-and-forth - all I remember is posting one comment on your first answer saying that it didn't work for me, and one comment clarifying that I am not the OP. I still believe that if your second answer was correct (I didn't get the chance to see), then it would be useful to others with the same problem, and shouldn't have been deleted. As a side note, to reply to me (and not the OP, who is different), you will need to use the (@) notation to reply to my comment, so that it shows up in my inbox.

Comment: @max, I thought the blog post you linked to was related to the actual OP question about flexbox+box-sizing, not the question about getting snippets in a post. Not that you can really edit it now, but just keep in mind for the future which question you are responding to, and for others, that blog isn't about flexbox+box-sizing... keep on lookin'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define the `height` in order for the `box-sizing` to work.

I added `height: 25.3%;` in the following code, which means `(300px-25px*2-10px*6)/((300px-25px*2)*3)`, and the code works.

http://jiayuanpulto.github.io/test/test_box-sizing.html