# Why does the input move when focused?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div surrounding an input and a button and whenever the input is focused, it moves. How can I get it to stop moving?

Here is my html:

```
<div class="search">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar" placeholder="What do you want to learn about?" />
    <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

input{
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }

  .is-focused{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #986fa5;
  }

  input:focus{
    outline-width: 0px;
  }

  .search * {
        height: 35px;

    }

    /*.search-button{
        position: absolute;
    }*/

    .searchbar {
        width: 450px;
    }
```

and here is my js/jquery:

```
$('input').focus(
function(){
    $('.input-container').addClass('is-focused');
}).blur(
function(){
    $('.input-container').removeClass('is-focused');
});
```

I also have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26654/) where you can see the input moving when focused.

Comment: It's because you used a border. The border will move your element. See the answers to use outline, this won't move your element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change

```
 .is-focused{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #986fa5;
  }
```

to

```
.is-focused{
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #986fa5;
  }
```

Can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26655/)

Comment: this works. How come the border makes it move though?

Comment: @user3494047 Basically because borders take up space on the page and outlines don't. It's something you wouldn't know right away, but [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/outline_style.htm) is an article about it and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158515/difference-between-outline-and-border) is an answer about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use outline

```
 .is-focused{
    outline-style: solid;
    outline-color: #986fa5;
  }
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/04x6018h/

or use negative margins (not recommended):

```
 .is-focused{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #986fa5;
    margin:-3px;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/04x6018h/1/

or box-shadow

```
 .is-focused {
   box-shadow: 0  0 0 3px #986fa5;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/04x6018h/2/

Answer (score 0):

It's because size of border, you can use `:before` pseudo element with `position:absolute;` to solve issue.

```js
$('input').focus(function(){$('.input-container').addClass('is-focused');}).blur(function(){$('.input-container').removeClass('is-focused');});
```

```css
body { margin: 10px; }

input {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-indent: 5px;
}
input:focus{ outline-width: 0px; }

.is-focused { position:relative;}
.is-focused:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #986fa5;
}

.search * { height: 35px; }
.searchbar { width: 450px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar" placeholder="What do you want to learn about?" />
    <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A [`border`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) expands your element by it's border width, while an [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) does not. Simply replace your outlines by borders and the jumping will be removed.

```js
$('input').focus(function() {
  $('.input-container').addClass('is-focused');
}).blur(function() {
  $('.input-container').removeClass('is-focused');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}
input {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
.is-focused {
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: #986fa5;
}
input:focus {
  outline-width: 0px;
}
.search * {
  height: 35px;
}
/*.search-button{
        position: absolute;
    }*/

.searchbar {
  width: 450px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input type="text" name="query" class="searchbar" placeholder="What do you want to learn about?" />
    <button type="submit" class="search-button">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
```