# White Gap Between Border and Inner Object CSS

Tags: css

**EDIT: idk when they fixed it but now it's ok in chrome**

When I have a parent element with a border, and an element on the inside, there is always a little white gap on all sides. This is despite me setting the inner padding and outer margin both to 0.
Example:

```css
#outer{
    height:10px;
    width:200px;
    border:2px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:999px;
    padding:0;
}
#inner{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Chrome I suspect this is due to pixel rounding &/or anti-aliasing.

Comment: Or depending on the display type of the parent vs children simply having them on newlines can cause a spacing artifact whereas `<div id="outer"><div id="inner"></div></div>` with no space between the tags will sometimes resolve the issue.

Comment: That's a browser issue - in Firefox for example there is no gap.

Comment: How do I write it so it works in chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use outline instead of border.

ref: [What is the difference between outline and border CSS properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158515/what-is-the-difference-between-outline-and-border-css-properties#:%7E:text=Border%20is%20created%20inside%20the,outline%20draws%20outside%20the%20element.)

```css
#outer{
    height:10px;
    width:200px;
    outline:2px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-radius:999px;
    padding:0;
}
#inner{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:red;
    margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```