# Can't remove checkbox original border

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, jsreport

I'm trying to create 2 checkboxex and customize them so they look like a square with black border instead the original gray rounded border.
I'm using jsreport studio.

HTML code:

```
    <div class="checkboxTable">
        <div class="row">
            {{#if Racunala}}
                <div class="cell"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked> računala</input></div>
            {{else}}
                <div class="cell"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> računala</input></div>
            {{/if}}

            {{#if Mobiteli}}
                <div class="cell"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked> mobiteli</input></div>
            {{else}}
                <div class="cell"><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> mobiteli</input></div>
            {{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
    accent-color: white;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    
}

.checkboxTable {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
```

I expected for this code

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
    accent-color: white;
    outline: 1px solid black;
    
}
```

to change the border but looks like it added a new one around the original one(also when the checbox is 'checked' then the original border disappears like on the screenshot I posted).
Can I somehow remove it?

[image]

Comment: Customising checkbox controls via borders/backgrounds etc is notoriously unreliable. I would suggest implementing a different method if you want to create this UX. Eg. something like this: https://moderncss.dev/pure-css-custom-checkbox-style/

Comment: Also `outline` and `border` are separate css properties. ... 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158515/what-is-the-difference-between-outline-and-border-css-properties

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the source.
But since I'm using jsreport and generating PDFs(so there is no user interaction like clicking on the checbox) I wasn't able to resolve my issue.
If I reset the native checkbox input style(so I can change border style) like in the tutorial then in my code in if else statements doesn't work and what I mean by that is it doesn't display the tick when condition is true.
So I guess then I would have to somehow insert tick icon in the customized checbox if my condition is true?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -o-appearance:none;
    outline: none;
    content: none;  
}
```